# Folder not being created with $cfg['UploadDir']

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

Just started SQL Essentials on Lynda.com to get familiar with SQL.

In the process of setting up a test environment, there's a step where we need to add `$cfg['UploadDir'] = 'c:\Files';` on `config.php.inc` file.

The expected result is the folder Files is made on the C drive. But it's not being created.

Any insights on why am i not able to create such folder?

Comment: Do you have folder write permission?

Comment: Thanks Shivan. Just checked to confirm that I do have write permission to C: Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about that tutorial, but apparently it's wrong.

The expected result is not that phpMyAdmin creates that folder; rather you're supposed to create the folder yourself, make sure it has adequate permissions for your webserver, and finally add it to `config.inc.php`. (Technically the order doesn't matter, but this is the simplest way).

You may also wish to reference the [official documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_UploadDir) for the full explanation of this directive.

Comment: It could very well be i might have understood the instruction incorrectly :(
I will try that and update you. Thanks for your time!!